# Exposing lookup interface for MemoryCache in a windows service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-services, memorycache

Using .net 4.6, I have a windows service which has a timer that wakes up everyday at a configured time, connects to a remote database and caches some data in memory using the MemoryCache class:

```
        string id = rec.ID;
        string surname = rec.Surname;
        string dateOfBirth = rec.DateOfBirth;
        string agreement = rec.Agreement;                        
        CachedData cd = new CachedData(id, surname, dateOfBirth, agreement);

        MemoryCache.Default.Set(id, cd, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)));
```

I need to expose a lookup interface on this MemoryCache. I have a separate WCF service which exposes a lookup interface but I don't know how to communicate the lookup request/result between the WCf service and windows service so if I get an id in the WCf service:

```
string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("id");
```

I could pass it on to the windows service which would look it up in memory cache and return a result.

I followed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx to host a wcf service in a windows service. At the end I just added the following to the OnStart() method of the Service1.cs class of my WindowsService:

```
MemoryCache.Default.Set("K", "Hello World", new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)));
```

and assuming that because the WCF service (also called Service1.cs) is now hosted by the windows service and will share the same app domain, I modified the default GetData method in the WCF as follows:

```
    public string GetData(int value)
    {            
        var kv = MemoryCache.Default["K"] as string;
        if (kv != null)
        {
            return kv;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format("Entered: {0}", value);
        }            
    }
```

However when I use the test client and call the GetData it can't find the cached item in the MemoryCache.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get to MemoryCache instance from another process that hosts your WCF service.

Can you host `WCF` service inside `Windows Service`? In that case it won't be any issue to use `MemoryCahce` instance updated by timer in WCF service.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit of the original post as I could not put it all here.

Comment: @user1984695, It hard to says as you did not provide the minimal program that would run. I suggest you to check that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` are same in both places when you work with cache. Also you can check whether setting up <memoryCache> configuration would help you - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941872(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a (persistent) cache outside your application, that way you can have multiple instance, make deploys and so on without losing your cached data (what happens if your windows services goes tits up within those 24h today?). Memcached and Redis are the first ones that I think of.

Comment: I am aware of the cons of having in-memory cache. This is a requirement for this task and part of it is that the cache will be rebuilt when the service is back up (when things go wrong).